# jquery ajax queue is not executing proeperly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function myfucntion(){

$.ajaxQueue({complete: function () {

        var revisionXml = sessionStorage.getItem('eB.UI.revision.xml');
        var productXmlDoc = sessionStorage.getItem('eB.UI.productDetails' + '_' + sessionStorage.getItem('eB.UI.product.id'));
        var productXml = $(productXmlDoc).find('productXML:first').text();

        var topILItems = null;
        topILItems = $(revisionXml).find('E').filter(function () {
            return $(this).find("cat:first").text() === "60" && $(this).parent().find("cat:first").text() === "100";
        });

        var listItems = null;

        var previewWindow =window.open("../rest/extractservice/getSummaryBOQExtract?topILItems="+topILItems);
        window.focus();


    }});

}
```

//i am opening a preview window at the end of my ajax queue ..but instead of all the previous code being executed, window.open is getteng executed, which means by that time topILItems not evaluated yet.

Comment: Doesn't even seem to be a relationship between the window open code and the other code in the ajaxQueue

Comment: I indented the code more properly, but it is invalid code. Braces missing and not matching, quotes not closed. Do at least an effort to post syntactically correct code.

Comment: You should use `success` function instead of `complete`, and what is `appContext`? Check `console.log` for errors as well. You're not closing your `previewWindow` either. `var previewWindow = window.open(appContext + 
               "/rest/extractservice/getSummaryBOQExtract");
        window.focus();`